# jquery click even with a tag without href

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have main page where I define a DIV with id "mydiv". Then I use ajax to load some linked text inside that DIV.

Now I want to do something when anybody click on those links, so I defined my jquery like below.

```
$("#mydiv > a").live('click',function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

The loaded contents are in the below form

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;">Text 1</a>
<a style="cursor:pointer;">Text 2</a>
<a style="cursor:pointer;">Text 3</a>
```

Anybody please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: which jquery version are you using? Even if `live` is deprecated (and removed on 1.9.0) it should work anyway on 1.8 and older.

Comment: works fine here  http://jsfiddle.net/8EzKG/  using jQuery 1.8.  Are `<a>` tags direct children of `mydiv`?

Comment: I am using jquery 1.8.3 ...

Comment: wow .. if it is works fine is jsfiddle, let me search my whole code again .. what might be the issue

Comment: switch to `on()` as others have shown, I'm guessing the `<a>` have other ancestors inside the DIV and selector is wrong using `>`

Comment: @charlietfl ... yaa, I just found that ... I missed that thing before .. thanks for clarification .. and thanks to all for kind help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you are loading the content inside `DIV with id "mydiv"` dynamically (by ajax)....use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegate event

```
$("#mydiv").on('click','a',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();  //you may not need this... but this stops the default behaviour of <a> tag 
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: this is working !! strange, I am using 1.8.3 so live should have worked as well ... anyway, thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

You may use like this. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/muthusamy/2VvrW/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("a").on('click',function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});

});
```

html

```
 <a style="cursor:pointer;">Text 1</a>
<a style="cursor:pointer;">Text 2</a>
<a style="cursor:pointer;">Text 3</a>
```

Comment: this use of `on` will not delegate the handler for `<a>` tags and is not a replacement for `live` as is

Answer (score 1):

As you are loading your contents dynamically `.on()` handler will be used for this in **jQuery version 1.9.0**:

You have to `delegate the event` to the `nearest existing parent` or directly to `document`(which is parent of all other elems).

```
$("#mydiv").on('click','a', function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

or:

```
$(document).on('click','#mydiv a', function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: `on` goes back farther than jQuery 1.9

Comment: if jquery version 1.9.0 used.